# mysql composite primary key - "insert on duplicate key" does not work as expected

Tags: mysql

**TL;DR**:
SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bec3/1
Why has `row_was_updated` been updated?

## Background

I have a daemon that runs multiple instances on several hosts (one daemon instance per host) for redundancy. At all times, only one of those instances should be the active one. All the others must wait for the active instance to die before they take over the 'active' status.

I have a MySQL table that I use to keep track of all the daemon instances, and also to keep track of which instance is the active one. The first instance to insert a value of **1** into the `active` column becomes the active one. All instances keep writing the current time to the `last_active` column. There is a MySQL trigger that deletes any row of which the value of the `last_active` column is older than 30 seconds. If the active instance fails to update its `last_active` value - because it crashed - its row will be deleted by the database and one other instance will become the active one.

## Table

```
CREATE TABLE `DT_ActiveCommandModules` (
    `host` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'latin1_general_cs',
    `active` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_active` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `row_was_updated` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`host`, `name`),
UNIQUE INDEX `each command module can have only one active instance` (`name`, `active`)
);
```

## The idea

Each instance runs the same *insert..on duplicate key update* query, with its own values. If the query fails, the instance knows that it did not become the active instance, and must therefore wait a while and try again. If the query succeeds, the instance is the active instance, and its `last_active` value has been updated.

So as an example, the first instance of the daemon named **TEST** (on host **1**) executes this query (on an empty table):

```
INSERT INTO DT_ActiveCommandModules 
    (host, name, active, last_active, row_was_updated) 
VALUES
    (1,'TEST',1,now(), 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    active=1,
    last_active=NOW();
```

And becomes the active instance. Then the second instance of daemon **TEST** (on host **2**) executes this query:

```
INSERT INTO DT_ActiveCommandModules 
    (host, name, active, last_active, row_was_updated) 
VALUES
    (2,'TEST',1,now(), 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    active=1,
    last_active=NOW();
```

## The problem

I expected the second query to fail because of the UNIQUE constraint on (name,active). Strangely enough it does not fail. Even stranger, it then proceeds to update the `last_active` value of the instance on host **1**.

So first it does not match the unique key, but then apparently it *does* match the primary key (that has different values, host=1 vs host=2)???

I created this SQL fiddle to show the behaviour: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bec3/1
I added the `row_was_updated` bit to show that the query from the simulated second instance does update the row from the first instance. I really don't understand why it does that.

## The questions

1. Why doesn't the second query match the unique key?
2. Why does it match the primary key that has different values?
3. How do I fix the query to do what I want? ;-)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) clause triggers on both duplicate `PRIMARY KEY` or duplicate `UNIQUE KEY`.

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row.

So here `'TEST', 1` matches the unique constraint, irrelevant of the `host` part of the primary key, causing the clause to update what really is the instance active on another host.